# Lint and tests only for debug variant

Tags: android, gradle

We're running CI server which runs checks for each commit.

```
./gradlew check
```

But it take ages, because it builds release build with ProGuard, etc. But when I try to run it with just debug variant, no tests and lint checks are run, it just finishes immediately.

```
./gradlew checkDebug
```

It's a bit WTF for me. How can we do that?